# Subsequences. Prove that (xn) is bounded. Prove that (xn) converges to x.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let x be a real number, and suppose (xn) is a sequence such that every subsequence (xnk ) of (xn) has a subsequence (xnkj ) that converges to x.
(a) Prove that (xn) is bounded. 
(b) Prove that (xn) converges to x.

I think I see what is going on in this exercise. But I don't see how to work backwards clearly. From sub subsequence back to the original sequence and have a rigorous proof.

Here is my attempt.

I started first by stating that lim Xnkj=x and Xnkj is bounded.

So for every   ε > 0 exists N, such that n>N implies |xnkj-x|<ε for all n>N.

But I don't see how do I go backwards for proving that Xnk is bounded first.

Thanks for help
I still need help with part b. Comments are below.

Comment: Can someone help with part b? I know I have to start with a contradiction that lim Xn is not x. And if lim Xn is not x, then how do I get a contradiction? Don't seek to see the whole picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is not bounded.  Then given $N > 0$ there exists $|x_N| > N$.  But then we have a subsequence that tends to infinity contradicting that every subsequence converges to $x$.

2) $x_n \to x$  Suppose not.  Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ and $n_1, n_2, ...$ such that
$|x_{n_k} - x| \geq \epsilon$ contradicting that every subsequence converges to $x$.

Comment: I can't understand your logic for part b, can you deliberate please?

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence $(x_n)$ NOT to converge to a point $x$ ?  Try to write down the negation of the statement $x_n \to x$.

Comment: I finally proofed, but I used different approach. I used subsequential limit set and bolzano  weiertrass theorem to get a contradiction.